# Three DIVs, two are closely, one is left-shifted

Tags: html, css

Have a structure:

```
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

How can I make div3 floating left to div2, and then make a left shift on div2?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```css
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
#div2 {
  float: right;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}
#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  div 1
  <div id="div2">div 2</div>
</div>
<div id="div3">div 3</div>
```

Here is  jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nmsptskp/

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block` on all 3 div & `float:right` on div2

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#div2 {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#div3 {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is using flexbox css

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

#div1{
  flex-grow: 1;
  border:5px solid #ccc;
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: col;
}
#div2{
  width: 50%;
  text-align:center;
  border:5px solid #000;
  self-
}
#div3{
  flex-grow: 1;
  border:5px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1">
    div 1
     <div id="div2"> div 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div3"> div 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float left and right

```html
<style>
 #div1{width:300px;height:50px;background:green;margin:10px;float:left;}
 #div2{width:100px;height:50px;background:red;float:right;opacity:0.7}
 #div3{width:100px;height:50px;background:yellow;margin:10px;float:left;}
</style>
<div id="div1">
   <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```